# Convert string to directory object in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I read strings line by line from a file (using Get-Content and a foreach loop), I want to convert those strings to directory objects (so that I can access properties like `.FullName`). How to easily convert from string to directory?

With files it is easy: `$myFileAsFile = $myFileAsStr | dir $_`, however, how to obtain my goal for a `$directoryAsString`?

Comment: Do you mean `$myFileAsFile = $myFileAsStr | dir { $_ }`?  Otherwise I don't see how that could ever work.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Okay, the answer seems to be `Get-Item`:

```
$dirAsStr = '.\Documents'
$dirAsDir = Get-Item $dirAsStr
echo $dirAsDir.FullName
```

Works!

Comment: This will only work if the item actually *exists*. From your question it is not clear whether the strings in the file relate to real directories or not

Comment: In my case they always exist - do you have a better solution working in the general case as well?

Comment: To handle the folder possibly not existing: if(Test-Path $dirAsStr){$dirAsDir = Get-Item $dirAsStr}else{$dirAsDir = md $dirAsStr}

Answer (score 23):

You can use .Net class `System.IO.FileInfo` or `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`. This will work even if directory does not exist:

```
$c = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]"C:\notexistentdir"
$c.FullName
```

It will even work with a file:

```
$c = [System.IO.DirectoryInfo]"C:\some\file.txt"
$c.Extension
```

So to check if it is really a directory use:

```
$c.Attributes.HasFlag([System.IO.FileAttributes]::Directory)
```

There's an example with `System.IO.FileInfo` in the comment below.

Comment: Adding this for others that ended up here looking for the directory off a string of a filename. You can use `[System.IO.FileInfo]$filename = "File path here"` to get a file object. Then you can use `$filename.directory` to get it's directory. Slightly off topic, but just in case you, the reader,  landed here the same way I did.

Comment: <redacted for dumb mistake>

Comment: This method does not deal with relative paths, where Get-Item does. Not sure if it affects anyone else, but it did for my use case.  `([System.IO.FileInfo]'.\myfile.txt').FullName` produces **C:\Windows\System32\myfile.txt** regardless of what the current folder is.

Comment: DirectoryInfo class has SetCurrentDirectory method. And I don't think it uses or should use PowerShell environment

Answer (score 5):

So, the simple way for get path/full path from string type variable, that always works to me:

```
(Resolve-Path $some_string_var)
```

---

```
Set-Variable -Name "str_path_" -Value "G:\SO_en-EN\Q33281463\Q33281463.ps1"

$fullpath = (Resolve-Path $some_string_var) ; $fullpath
```

---

Comment: why $ in front of (Resolve-Path ...) ?

Comment: @user310291 distraction  only this, thk for comment d:)

Answer (score 1):

Get-item will output a fileinfo or directoryinfo object depending on the input.  Or pipe to `get-item -path { $_ }`.

```
$myFileAsFile = get-item $myFileAsStr
$directoryAsDir = get-item $directoryAsString
```

Answer (score 0):

The quick way

```
# "Get-Item" automatically grabs $Path item as an object if it exists.
# Carry on your merry way.
$FSO = Get-Item -Path $Path -Force
```

The above works but is susceptible to bad input. So, combine with some of the previous comments and a little input validation...

```
# Get path string (via parm, pipeline, etc.)
# Can be full path ('c:\users\Me') or properly formatted relative path ('..\..\Logs').
$Path = '<some_string>'

# Never presume the input actually exists, so check it with "Test-Path".
# Note: If the string is a file and ends with "\", this check will fail (generate an error).
# YMMV: add add'l code to strip off trailing "\" unless it's a drive (e.g., "C:\") prior to the check.
if (Test-Path $Path -PathType Leaf) {
    $PathType = 'File'
} elseif (Test-Path $Path -PathType Container) {
    $PathType = 'Folder'
} else {$PathType = $null}

# "Get-Item" automatically grabs item as an object if it exists.
if ($PathType) {
    $FSO = Get-Item -Path $Path -Force
    Write-Host 'Object is:' $PathType
    Write-Host 'FullName: ' $FSO.FullName
} else {
    Write-Host 'Bad path provided.'
    exit
}

# Some Test-Path samples:
$Path = 'c:\windows\'             # Folder: Test-Path works
$Path = 'c:\windows'              # Folder: Test-Path works
$Path = 'c:\windows\system.ini'   # File: Test-Path works
$Path = 'c:\windows\system.ini\'  # File: Test-Path FAILS
$Path = '..\system.ini'           # File: Test-Path works
$Path = '..\system.ini\'          # File: Test-Path FAILS
```

The above is kinda kludgy, so, tighten things up...

- Handle the trailing "\" problem
- Using ".GetType()" on a FSO will indicate the object type allowing for specific processing.

```
# Get path string (via parm, pipeline, etc.)
$Path = '<some_string>'

# Remove trailing "\" on all but drive paths (e.g., C:\, D:\)
if ($Path.EndsWith("\")) {
    if ($Path.Length -gt 3) {
        $Path = $Path.Remove($Path.Length - 1)
    }
}

# If the provided path exists, do stuff based on object type
# Else, go another direction as necessary
if (Test-Path -Path $Path) {
    $FSO = Get-Item -Path $Path -Force
    if ($FSO.GetType().FullName -eq "System.IO.DirectoryInfo") {
        Write-Host "Do directory stuff."
    } elseif ($FSO.GetType().FullName -eq "System.IO.FileInfo") {
        Write-Host "Do file stuff."
    } else {
         Write-Host "Valid path, but NOT a file system object!! (could be a registry item, etc.)"
    }
    Write-Host $FSO.FullName
} else {
    Write-Host "Path does not exist. Bail or do other processing, such as creating the path."
    $FSO = $null
}
```

Answer (score -2):

$(Get-Item $directoryAsString).FullName